# What can prevent IE10 from accepting multiple file uploads

Tags: html, forms, file-upload, internet-explorer-10

I am running IE10, and attemping to enable multiple file uploads from a single html input.

I have gone back to absolute basics, and used example code from w3schoools to test the functionality.

If I go here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_multiple and click browse, I am able to select multiple files.

If I copy all of the code and paste into an empty html document on my internal webserver, and navigate to that page, I can not select multiple files.

Is there some IE security setting that can prevent this ability based on site zone or security etc? Or perhaps a setting within Apache 2.2.4 that disables this?

EDIT: I have just tested the same code locally with chrome, and it works fine, so assume it is not my web server, but some setting in IE10.

Comment: Make sure you are not running IE10 in compatibility mode.

Comment: It's not, the compatibility view button doesn't even appear in the browser when I visit this page.

Comment: Not reproducible. Even in Quirks Mode, IE 10 lets me select multiple files when testing locally.

Comment: Not sure what or how, but I added <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> to try to get the page to run in what I believe to be IE9 mode. Adding that line cured the problem. I then removed the line, and it still worked :S

Comment: I have noticed, adding that line, the form works correctly, removing it and reloading the page works correctly. If I then navigate away from that page, and then go back to it after removing that line, it no longer works.

Comment: Ok I must apologise to roflmao, as when going into developer tools, the browser is running in IE10 compat mode, IE7 quirks. The compatibility view button does not appear, so I don't know how normal users are supposed to turn this off? How can I stop this page auto starting in compat mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by the OP, the issue at hand is most likely a (mis-configured) `X-UA-Compatible` meta-tag.

I suggest to **remove the `X-UA-Compatible` tag** altogether these days, except for very specific edge cases.

I have successfully "enabled" multi-file upload for a legacy application this way. More details:

- [What does <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do)
- https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-multiple